# How to have a direct link to app insights page view without being hard coded?

Tags: asp.net, azure, appinsights

Is there a way to have a quick link to App Insights Page Views from my Asp.Net App without having the generated link from "Copy link" hard coded?

[image]

Comment: What would be the dynamic part?

Comment: the parameters should be to see the page views from the last 30 days